# Django serve multiple domains with a single instance

Tags: django, nginx, web-hosting, gunicorn

In order to save on costs and take full advantage of the hardware I'm paying for, I want to use a single Django instance to serve up my enterprise application on multiple domains/subdomains. The database used for a given request depends on the domain that request is made to. Otherwise, the only differences between what is served up to each domain/subdomain are easily controlled via Django configuration files.

How can I do this with a single Django instance?

Additional information: I plan on using nginx with gunicorn for deployment.

Edit: By "single Django instance", I mean that there would be only one instantiated Django instance. I want to avoid running the same Django code five times on the same machine in order to serve up five hosts.

Comment: You should take a look over the sites docs; https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/sites/

Comment: I've examined that, but it appears to use a single database instance. I can see that being useful in some situations, but in mine, I need to keep the data for each host in separate databases for several reasons, not the least of which being that I need independent db backups.

Comment: Which method did you go with for this in the end, out of interest? I'm looking at doing something very similar and am not sure which way to go myself.

Answer (score 1):

Please figure out if you can try this.

in a middleware module, check what is the hostname. set the DB based on the hostname.

```
import socket

try:
    hostname = socket.gethostname()
except:
    hostname = 'default'

if hostname == 'site1.com':

  DATABASES = {
      'default': {
          'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
          'NAME': 'site1DB',
          'USER': 'root',
          'PASSWORD': '*****',
          'HOST': 'localhost',   
          'PORT': '3306',
      }
  }


elif hostname == 'site2.com':

  DATABASES = {
      'default': {
          'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
          'NAME': 'site2DB',
          'USER': 'root',
          'PASSWORD': '*****',
          'HOST': 'localhost',   
          'PORT': '3306',
      }
  }
```

Also please if **Django routers** **(https://docs.djangoproject.com/ja/1.9/topics/db/multi-db/)** is helpful.

Comment: This definitely looks interesting. I'll have to dig on it to see if there are any performance problems from settings conditioned on the hostname, but this definitely looks promising.

Comment: Would this kill the benefits of database connection pools?

Comment: @adam, Multiple DBs(routers) is part of Django itself(so I assume connection pool problem is taken care of). But routers are little different. But I would always recommend with Django Routers. I believe we can switch DB based(in middleware) on the site current_url .

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options, which really depends on what you are trying to achieve.

There is this Django app https://github.com/bernardopires/django-tenant-schemas where you can setup multiple databases schemas and serve the requests based on the subdomain. I never tried it though.

---

I actually had a similar problem once. I needed 7 independent instances of my application, for an usability experiment and I didn't want to add any extra dependency, because it was temporary.

I cloned my repository in the Ubuntu server, and there I created 7 different databases (db_1, db_2, ..., db_7) and created 7 settings file:

**settings_1.py**

```
from django_app.settings import *

ENVIRONMENT_NAME = 'Test Environment 1'

DATABASES = {
    'default': dj_database_url.config(
        default = 'postgres://u_db:123@localhost:5432/db_1' 
    )
}

MEDIA_ROOT = PROJECT_DIR.parent.parent.child('media').child('_1')
```

**settings_2.py**

```
from django_app.settings import *

ENVIRONMENT_NAME = 'Test Environment 2'

DATABASES = {
    'default': dj_database_url.config(
        default = 'postgres://u_db:123@localhost:5432/db_2' 
    )
}

MEDIA_ROOT = PROJECT_DIR.parent.parent.child('media').child('_2')
```

And so on... Basically I was importing my project settings and overriding the parameters I needed, i.e., the database

Then after that I created a **gunicorn_start** script for each of my environments:

**gunicorn_start_1**

```
#!/bin/bash

NAME="django_app_1"
DJANGODIR=/opt/django_app/django_app
SOCKFILE=/opt/django_app/run/gunicorn_1.sock
USER=app_user
GROUP=django_apps
NUM_WORKERS=3
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=django_app.settings_1
DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE=django_app.wsgi

cd $DJANGODIR
source ../bin/activate
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=$DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE
export PYTHONPATH=$DJANGODIR:$PYTHONPATH

RUNDIR=$(dirname $SOCKFILE)
test -d $RUNDIR || mkdir -p $RUNDIR

exec ../bin/gunicorn ${DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE}:application \
  --name $NAME \
  --workers $NUM_WORKERS \
  --user=$USER --group=$GROUP \
  --bind=unix:$SOCKFILE \
  --log-level=error \
  --log-file=-
```

**gunicorn_start_2**

```
#!/bin/bash

NAME="django_app_2"
DJANGODIR=/opt/django_app/django_app
SOCKFILE=/opt/django_app/run/gunicorn_2.sock
USER=app_user
GROUP=django_apps
NUM_WORKERS=3
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=django_app.settings_2
DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE=django_app.wsgi

cd $DJANGODIR
source ../bin/activate
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=$DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE
export PYTHONPATH=$DJANGODIR:$PYTHONPATH

RUNDIR=$(dirname $SOCKFILE)
test -d $RUNDIR || mkdir -p $RUNDIR

exec ../bin/gunicorn ${DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE}:application \
  --name $NAME \
  --workers $NUM_WORKERS \
  --user=$USER --group=$GROUP \
  --bind=unix:$SOCKFILE \
  --log-level=error \
  --log-file=-
```

And did the same thing for the rest.

Each of the instances had its own nginx config file:

**app_1** (nginx config)

```
upstream app_server_1 {
  server unix:/opt/django_app/run/gunicorn_1.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    listen   80;
    server_name env1.mydomain.com;
    client_max_body_size 4G;

    access_log /opt/django_app/logs/nginx-access_1.log;
    error_log /opt/django_app/logs/nginx-error_1.log;

    location /static/ {
        alias   /opt/django_app/static/;
    }

    location /media/ {
        alias   /opt/django_app/media/_1/;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        if (!-f $request_filename) {
            proxy_pass http://app_server_1;
            break;
        }
    }

}
```

**app_2** (nginx config)

```
upstream app_server_2 {
  server unix:/opt/django_app/run/gunicorn_2.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    listen   80;
    server_name env2.mydomain.com;
    client_max_body_size 4G;

    access_log /opt/django_app/logs/nginx-access_2.log;
    error_log /opt/django_app/logs/nginx-error_2.log;

    location /static/ {
        alias   /opt/django_app/static/;
    }

    location /media/ {
        alias   /opt/django_app/media/_2/;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        if (!-f $request_filename) {
            proxy_pass http://app_server_2;
            break;
        }
    }

}
```

After that I configured a supervisor for each of the instances and configured the DNS of my domain.

So basically I had a shared Django source code and static files, and independent media folder, log files and databases.

---

Probably it is not the best approach, but I managed to achieve what I needed at the time

Comment: When you have multiple gunicorn configs, nginx configs, etc. you wind up with multiple processes running the same code. If this is the best way to go, I'll run with it, but I would much prefer pointing all hosts to the same running instance in order to conserve server capacity.